# How to add a single file to an existing snapshot timestamp version in Sonatype Nexus

Tags: maven, versioning, nexus, snapshot

I am working on a CI/CD pipeline for Jenkins, which is used by various projects. All projects use Maven and deploy their snapshot and release versions to a given Artifact Repository.

In the pipeline I also create a file and deploy it via [`mvn deploy:deploy-file`](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/deploy-file-mojo.html) with the same snapshot version, e.g. 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT, to the used repository. Hence the actual deployment of the project was done before, a new timestamped snapshot version is created.

In the used repository, it looks like this:

```
─┬─ my-artifact
 │  ├─ 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT
 │  ├─ 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123453-1
 │  │  └ ...
 │  ├─ 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123463-2
 │  │  ├─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123463-2.jar
 │  │  ├─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123463-2.jar.md5
 │  │  ├─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123463-2.jar.sha1
 │  │  ├─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123463-2.pom
 │  │  ├─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123463-2.pom.md5
 │  │  └─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123463-2.pom.sha1
 │  └── 1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123473-3
 │      ├─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123473-3-cyclonedx.xml
 │      ├─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123473-3-cyclonedx.xml.md5
 │      └─ my-artifact-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123473-3-cyclonedx.xml.sha1
```

As you can see, the snapshot version `1.2.3-SNAPSHOT-20201215.123473-3`, uploaded by my pipeline code, has a totally different content then the previous version. Any Maven project requesting the latest snapshot version will fail to find the jar file, as the latest snapshot contains only the XML document.

Is there a way to deploy, or better to say, to attach an artifact to an existing timestamped snapshot version? I am afraid not, but I would like to validate my thoughts before choosing a totally different approah.

Within the pipeline I can do everything, execept modifying the POM of Maven project. Changing the Maven project is not possible, because there are many of them an the features I have to implement come from different stakeholders.

Comment: If you like to add a file you can use via https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/ (attach artifact)... sorry to fix a problem not to modify a project does not makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

khmarbaise is right.

You need to change the POM.

If the file should be part of the SNAPSHOT, it must be part of the Maven build.

If it has nothing to do with the build, you might better place it somewhere else.

Comment: It seems so, that the only solution is to upload it only for releases. I do this already now and for releases it works.

Comment: If I were you I would think about these files. If they belong to the build, try to change the build (even if it requires to change many places, you could e.g. use a parent POM for that), and if not, maybe another place it better suited for these files. Attaching files to a build outside of the build does not seem right.

Comment: I have the same oppinion as you have, but this is currently not possible.